# Debugging applications during development

Tags: development, vala

I wanted to start working on issue https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues/419 but I encountered a bug. So I wanted to debug the application code I added.

I found this tutorial on debugging vala code https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial but I'm not sure how to pass the correct build arguments to valac when using the meson build system.

Can anyone give me a tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile a Vala application using meson/ninja, it automatically adds the correct flags to make it build using debug information, so you can skip straight to debugging the application.